# Virtualbox and telnet

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port, telnet, serial-console

With the latest VirtualBox it is possible to set a tcp serial.
I have set port 2231 and with `telnet localhost 2231`,
the login prompt appears on my old Unix system.
The problems are:

- passwords are seen in clear text, and
- if I press the directional keys (up down left right) I see on the console

  ```
  giuseppe@att1:/home/giuseppe$ ^[[C^[[D^C
  ```

With an old version of `minicom` this does not appear.
Is there something to set with `telnet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

serial ports don't support the telnet TCP protocol, telnet is falling back to linemode,you need to disable telnet linemode so that it will use character mode.

type **ctrl-]**`mode character`**enter** and then log in.

Comment: using `nc` instead of telnet may also work, but you'd first have to put the tty into raw mode (not sure how to do that)